How to avoid request being upgraded to https
I have a simple express.js / React / vite app that is hosted on a digital ocean droplet.
Since it is mostly for studying/entertainment I didn't bother to buy a domain name and configure https. I was accessing the website directly through ip address (ex: 156.125.8.11:9999)
Without any changes in code all internal requests are being upgraded to https now. I still see http url in index.html, but the network request is using https, that obviously fails because no SSL is configured.
This is the html file, inspected using devtools:
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin="" src="http://156.125.8.11:9999/assets/index-DDRGdzOp.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="" href="http://156.125.8.11:9999/assets/index-n_ryQ3BS.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>

Yet, <script> and <link> are making https requests.
I have no special headers configured, vite config is fairly simple
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})

Had all the browsers received some security update recenlty?
How to get things working on http as it was before?

9999 might be an SSL port by default.  Why the odd port number?

Browsers might switch to HTTPS when  a) no explicit protocol was given (i.e. no explicit http:// in the URL) b) HSTS header was set by the destination c) HSTS is implied for the domain, as is for the dev TLD d) a redirect to HTTPS was sent by the server e) some browser extension did this. Check with developer tools what really is going on in your case, it is impossible to determine the cause based on the provided information alone.
